# No Audio in iOS 7

Tags: audio, ios7

I'm having trouble getting audio to play. I have a routine (see below) that I call. I get no errors. I have verified that the audio file is in the project and makes sound. My NSLogs in the routine tell me that the sound is playing. Speakers/volume all good. Any thoughts?

```
-(void) spaceBackgroundSound {

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/spaceBackground.aiff", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;


AVAudioPlayer *audioSpaceBackgroundSound;
audioSpaceBackgroundSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioSpaceBackgroundSound.numberOfLoops = -1;

audioSpaceBackgroundSound.volume = 1;
if (audioSpaceBackgroundSound == nil){
    NSLog(@"Got and error here");
}

else

NSLog(@"Background Sound Played");
[audioSpaceBackgroundSound play];

}
```

Comment: Please clarify if this is on iOS or OS X (I'm guessing OS X)

Comment: I guessed it was regarding iOS because OP originally stated Xcode 5, and with the abundance of mistagged questions where Xcode = iOS it's pretty safe to assume it.  If that guess is wrong feel free to change it.

Comment: this is iOS - for iPad.